# Dao object queryForId with a 0 length string as part of the argument?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make sense of some old code.

```
customerDao.queryForId("" + account.getId);
```

Is there a reason to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done to convert `getID` into a `String`. It cannot throw a `NullPointerException` as calling `getID.toString()` could if `getId` is `null`.